# Failed to build gem native extention (Ubuntu 14.04 on Codeanywhere)

Tags: ruby, sass, codeanywhere

I'm trying to install SASS on Codeanywhere project.

The process is explained here: http://docs.codeanywhere.com/advancedtopics/sass.html

I have succed to install ruby with first command but when I call second command

```
sudo gem install sass
```

get this error
[image: get this error]

If I call only...

```
gem install sass
```

get this error
[image: get this error2]

What to do?

Comment: Please post the error messages as text instead. That way search engines can index the question, and other people can find this post while googling for the same errors.

Comment: I know that but I can't copy from terminal. CTRL+C doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> `exec: autoreconf: not found`

It looks like you're missing `autoreconf`. It's present in the Ubuntu `autoconf` package:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install autoconf` have solved that issue below but "Failed to build gem native extention" still remains.

Comment: What's the error now? Add it to the question. Also make sure to read `gem_make.out` (displayed in the error message). Post the content too.